# Plotting arrows with different color in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a two dimensional array with 5 columns and some number of rows. The different columns have the following entries`x1 y1 x2 y2 z`
I want to plot an arrow from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2) and the color of the arrow should be taken from z column corresponding to some inbuilt colormap.
How can I do this matplotlib/python?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.cm as cmx

DATA = np.random.rand(5,5)

cmap = plt.cm.jet

cNorm  = colors.Normalize(vmin=np.min(DATA[:,4]), vmax=np.max(DATA[:,4]))

scalarMap = cmx.ScalarMappable(norm=cNorm,cmap=cmap)

for idx in range(0,len(DATA[:,1])):
    colorVal = scalarMap.to_rgba(DATA[idx,4])
    plt.arrow(DATA[idx,0],  #x1
              DATA[idx,1],  # y1
              DATA[idx,2]-DATA[idx,0], # x2 - x1
              DATA[idx,3]-DATA[idx,1], # y2 - y1
              color=colorVal)

plt.show()
```

You want to use `scalarMap.to_rgba` to turn your `z` value into an argument to pass to the `color` option of the `arrow` command.
Your result should look something like this:

[image]

**EDIT**
If you want to see the colorbar, too, things are a little bit more tricky. Here's an updated minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.cm as cmx
import matplotlib as mpl

DATA = np.random.rand(5,5)

cmap = plt.cm.jet

cNorm  = colors.Normalize(vmin=np.min(DATA[:,4]), vmax=np.max(DATA[:,4]))

scalarMap = cmx.ScalarMappable(norm=cNorm,cmap=cmap)

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.7, 0.85]) # [left, bottom, width, height]
axc = fig.add_axes([0.85, 0.10, 0.05, 0.85])

for idx in range(0,len(DATA[:,1])):
    colorVal = scalarMap.to_rgba(DATA[idx,4])
    ax.arrow(DATA[idx,0],  # x1
             DATA[idx,1],  # y1
             DATA[idx,2]-DATA[idx,0], # x2 - x1
             DATA[idx,3]-DATA[idx,1], # y2 - y1
             color=colorVal)

cb1 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(axc, cmap=cmap,
                                norm=cNorm,orientation='vertical')

plt.show()
```

Things to note:

- The additional `import matplotlib as mpl` to have access to the `ColorbarBase`
- Now, there is an explicit need to specify *two* axes, one for the arrows and one for the colorbar. This second set of axis should have a reasonable size for the colorbar.
  The `add_axes` command takes `[left, botton, width, height]` in relative units as input. So the right side is given by `left + width`.
- Plot the arrows on the first set of axis, `ax`, your initial figure.
- Plot the colobar on the second set of axis, `axc`. Pass the `cmap`, the normalization, `cNorm` and an orientation as arguments.

Your figure should look something like this:

[image]

**EDIT 2**

If you want a different colored edge on the arrows, change `color` to `facecolor` (or `fc`) and specify an `edgecolor` (`ec`). Additionally, you may now want to control the width of the arrow ([default = `0.001`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.arrow.html)) and the width of the head ([default = `3x width`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.arrow.html)).

```
plt.arrow(DATA[idx,0],  #x1
          DATA[idx,1],  # y1
          DATA[idx,2]-DATA[idx,0], # x2 - x1
          DATA[idx,3]-DATA[idx,1], # y2 - y1
          facecolor=colorVal,
          edgecolor='k',
          width=0.005,
          head_width=0.01)
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you could show how to plot the colorbar along with it as well, thanks

Comment: Is there a way to put edgecolor around an arrow? For example, the yellow one is hard to see unless there is a dark color edge. Also, what about a white arrow?