# Segment lines using pl.arrow() to show the directions

Tags: matplotlib, plot

I have a set of segment lines **AB**. Point **A** is located in `[x0,y0] = [0.0]` coordinate as being radial point. **B** is the end of segment lines `[x1,y1]`. I found some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748328/plotting-arrows-with-different-color-in-matplotlib) and I tried to adapt it to my problem.

**The question:** How can I plot radial segment showing that B is the end of arrow.? Because, in my code arrow sizes does exceed the plot window.

Any helps would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

def arrow_segment(AB):

    for idx in range(0,len(AB)):
            plt.arrow(AB[idx,0],  #x1
                  AB[idx,1],  # y1
                  AB[idx,2]-AB[idx,0], # x2 - x1
                  AB[idx,3]-AB[idx,1], # y2 - y1
                  color='blue',head_width=0.05, head_length=0.1)
    plt.show()
AB = [[0, 0., 1., 10]]
arrow_segment(AB)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you're asking what to do when the arrowhead is off the plot.  There are a few options:

1. You can draw the arrow up to the boundary and use a type of arrow head that indicates that it's not the true end of the arrow, such as a half arrow head, `"shape"="left"`, or open vs. closed, etc.
2. You can draw the arrowhead midway along the arrow, like is done for a streamline.  I don't know a command for this in mpl, but you could easily do it using two arrows, or just plotting a line and the head of an arrow, etc.

**Edit:**
For completeness, I'll add my take on a #2.  Here's I plot the line, and then plot the arrow over the line, and the arrowhead can be plotted anywhere along the line and in controlled by `f` (between 0 and 1).  The example shows a few lines plotted for `f` ranging from `0` to `.1`.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

def arrow_mh(v4, color, f=.5):
    x0, y0, x1, y1 = v4
    line = plt.plot([x0, x1], [y0, y1], color=color)

    f = max(f, .0001)
    dx = f*(x1-x0)
    dy = f*(y1-y0)
    a = plt.arrow(x0, y0, dx, dy,
          color=color,head_width=0.05, head_length=0.1)

def arrow_segment(AB):

    for idx in range(0,len(AB)):
        arrow_mh(AB[idx], 'blue', .01*(9-idx))
    plt.xlim(0, 1)
    plt.ylim(0, 1)
    plt.show()
AB = np.array([[.1*i, .1, .5, 4] for i in range(10)])
arrow_segment(AB)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank tom10, first option seems to be easiest way, but I tried. I simply put it after `head_length` Nothing has changed.

Comment: Yes, I see, I misinterpreted that keyword.  I guess option 2 would be your best bet as far as I know.