# Multiple colors for one PathPatch

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any way for me to have multiple colors on one matplotlib PathPatch? I have the following code and I want to, for instance, give each "segment" its own color (i.e. the segment from 0,0 to 0,1 can be red, from 0,1 to 2, 2 can be orange, from 4,3 to 5,3 can be yellow). I would like to do this without using Collections and just using the PathPatch

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()


verts = [(0,0), (0,1), (2,2), (4,3), (5,3)]
codes = [1,2,2,1,2]

pat = mpl.patches.PathPatch(mpl.patches.Path(verts, codes), fill=False, linewidth=2, edgecolor="red")
ax2.add_patch(pat)
ax2.set_xlim(-2, 6)
ax2.set_ylim(-2, 6)
```

Comment: `LineCollection` might also be helpful if you only have strait sections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't found a way of assigning an individual color to the segments of a `mpl.patches.Path` - and from [the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/path_api.html#matplotlib.path.Path), that does not appear to be possible (`Path` does not take any arguments related to its color/linewidth/etc.)

---

However - and as you state in your question - one can use [a `PathCollection`](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection) to combine individual [`PathPatches`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/artist_reference.html) of different colors.
The important argument is `match_original=True`.
For others in a similar situation, here is an example:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()


verts = [(0,0), (0,1), (2,2), (4,3), (5,3)]
codes = [[1,2],[1,2],[1,1],[1,2],[1,2]]

colors = ['red', 'orange', 'black', 'yellow']

pat = [mpl.patches.PathPatch(mpl.patches.Path(verts[i:i+2], codes[i]), fill=False, \ 
                      linewidth=2, edgecolor=colors[i]) for i in range(len(verts)-1)]

collection = mpl.collections.PatchCollection(pat, match_original=True)
ax2.add_collection(collection)

ax2.set_xlim(-2, 6)
ax2.set_ylim(-2, 6)

plt.show()
```

Things to note:

- `codes` now became a list of lists to identify each section individually
- `colors` is a list of strings with color identifiers. If you want to utilize a colormap, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18748959/2043505)
- The individual patches are stored in a list, `pat`, the looping is done in place
- All the patches in `pat` are assembled using `collections.PatchCollection` - here, **the important argument** is `match_original=True`, otherwise all lines will be the default black with a default line thickness

The above example produces this output:

[image: example]